# MD5SUM in a Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, md5sum

I'm trying to generate a MD5 checksum of a file in a Makefile. In my Makefile i have something like;

CHECKSUM=md5sum $(myfile)

But the variable CHECKSUM is always empty

Can anybody tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly different example, where I set the expected md5 value as a `make` variable, and then check against it inside the shell commands in my recipe. In this case, I wanted to download a specific version of Anaconda and check its md5sum before installing it.

Makefile:

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash
ANACONDA_MD5:=c989ecc8b648ab8a64731aaee9ed2e7e

none:

Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh: 
    wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh

download: Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh

verify: download
    AnacondaMD5="$$(md5sum Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh | cut -d ' ' -f1)" && \
    if [ "$$AnacondaMD5" == '$(ANACONDA_MD5)' ]; then echo "md5sum matches"; fi
```

Output:

```
$ make verify
wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
--2018-01-16 18:11:50--  https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
Resolving repo.continuum.io... 104.16.18.10, 104.16.19.10, 2400:cb00:2048:1::6810:130a, ...
Connecting to repo.continuum.io|104.16.18.10|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 550796553 (525M) [application/x-sh]
Saving to: `Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh'

100%[====================================================================================================================>] 550,796,553  103M/s   in 6.8s

2018-01-16 18:11:59 (77.0 MB/s) - `Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh' saved [550796553/550796553]

AnacondaMD5="$(md5sum Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh | cut -d ' ' -f1)" && \
    if [ "$AnacondaMD5" == 'c989ecc8b648ab8a64731aaee9ed2e7e' ]; then echo "md5sum matches"; fi
md5sum matches
```

Note the usage of `$$AnacondaMD5` to fill in the in-line `bash` variable vs. the usage of `$(ANACONDA_MD5)` to fill in the `make` variable

Version:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
```

Comment: single `=` instead of `==`: `if [ "$$AnacondaMD5" = '$(ANACONDA_MD5)' ];`

Comment: I use `SHELL:=/bin/bash` here so `==` [is ok](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16109/bash-double-equals-vs-eq)

Answer (score 1):

As Chris says, you need something like:

```
CHECKSUM=$(md5sum $(myfile))
```

In case you didn't know, CHECKSUM will only available on that line.  i.e. the following will output a blank link:

```
test:
    CHECKSUM=$(md5sum $(myfile))
    echo $$CHECKSUM
```

The following will do what you need:

```
test:
    CHECKSUM=$(md5sum $(myfile)); echo $$CHECKSUM
```

Or, if you need it over multiple lines

```
test:
    CHECKSUM=$(md5sum $(myfile)); \
    echo $$CHECKSUM; \
    echo $$CHECKSUM;
```

If you cut n paste the above, you need to insert tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the result of a command outside the commands-part in `makefile`?
Then, if your `make` is `GNU-make`, `$(shell)` function is available.
For example:

```
CHECKSUM := $(shell md5sum $(myfile))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
NOW=$$(date)
print-now:
    @echo $(NOW)
md5sum:
    @SUM=$$(md5sum file.txt | cut -d' ' -f 1); \
    echo $$SUM; \
    cp file.txt file.$${SUM}.txt; \
```

Now run it with `make md5sum`.

You should get file `file.<sum>.txt`.

If you copy code from above, remember to use `tab` for indent or get the file from repo https://github.com/rofrol/makefile-md5sum.

Answer (score 0):

For a list of files you can have following in Makefile

```
FILES=foo/bar/image.svg \
    foo/bar3/somejs.js \
    foo/bar1/someimage.svg \
    foo/bar2/anotherjs.js \
    foo/somestyle.css \
    html/block/somepng.png

checksum:
    for f in $(FILES); do \
    echo "file: $$f"; \
    SUM=$$(md5sum $$f | cut -d' ' -f 1); \
    echo "CHECKSUM: $$SUM"; \
    done
```